# How to aggregate SQL query and display result in a different column?

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate

I've a MY-SQL query which is pulling a set of records from database. I want to aggregate slightly different way to use in my application. When duplicate rows present in record set with same ticker value query will sum up est_units and est_trans_value and display in new columns as total_est_units and total_est_trans_value. If there is no duplicate with same ticker value it should display total_est_units as est_units and total_est_trans_value as est_trans_value. How can I do this -- Can you please help to modify this query?

SQL:

```
SELECT 
    oc.*
FROM
order_confirm_daily oc
    INNER JOIN
(SELECT 
    id, ticker, MAX(est_order_time) AS mts
FROM
    order_confirm_daily
WHERE DATE(est_order_time) LIKE '2021-04-26%'
GROUP BY ticker) ds ON ds.ticker = oc.ticker
    AND oc.est_order_time = ds.mts;
```

Sample Data:

[image]

desired results: Added two new derived column "total_est_units" and "Total_est_trans_value" which will display Sum of est_units and est_trans_value respectively only when multiple rows present with same ticker -- here it is "TNA" highlighted in screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of hte logic would be helpful.

Comment: Sample data, desired results is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see.  You just want window functions:

```
select oc.*,
       sum(est_units) over (partition by ticker) as total_est_units,
       sum(est_trans_value) over (partition by ticker) as total_est_trans_value
from order_confirm_daily oc;
```

EDIT:

In older versions of MySQL, you would use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
select *
from order_confirm_daily oc join
     (select ticker, sum(est_units) as total_est_units,
             sum(est_trans_value) as total_est_trans_value
      from order_confirm_daily oc
      group by ticker
     ) oct
     using (ticker);
```

Comment: Getting a syntax error.. right next to "over ( "Here is the Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by ticker) as total_est_units, sum(est_trans_value) over (part' at line 2 0.063 sec

Comment: I'm using mysql, Syntax would be different?

Comment: @Partha . . . No.  MySQL has supported window functions for years, since the 8.0 release.

Comment: @ Gordo .. Thank you. MySQL version I'm using 5.7.26. Interestingly when I run a simple Sum() it works but when I run a query with over (partition by ticker ) it shows error.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff -- Excellent Job! Thank you.